# How to make connections answer from the same gateway they entered in RouterOS?

Tags: routing, load-balancing, nat, mikrotik, routeros

I have a MikroTik RouterOS 6.23 device, and my network is as follows:

```
Router
  |
  |-- bridge1_LAN (wlan1 + ether1) (192.168.0.210) -- LAN (192.168.0.0/24)
  |   Here is where computers are. Those include some servers and some users.
  |   Users should be able to navigate always, and servers should
  |   be reachable online always.
  |
  |-- ether2_ADSL (192.168.2.2) -- ADSL router (192.168.2.1) -- WAN
  |   Users should navigate through here because there is no traffic limit.
  |   Incoming traffic should work exactly as with ether3_3G, as a temporary
  |   backup solution in case it fails.
  |
  |-- ether3_3G (192.168.3.2) -- 3G router (192.168.3.1) -- WAN
      This connection has a traffic limit, but faster upload rate, so it's
      mainly for incoming traffic. In case ether2_ADSL fails, this should be
      used as a temporary backup connection for outgoing traffic.
```

Now, the relevant configuration:

```
/ip firewall mangle

# This rule is disabled because, when enabled, users cannot browse Internet
add action=mark-routing chain=prerouting connection-mark=no-mark disabled=yes \
    in-interface=ether2_ADSL new-routing-mark=to_ether2_ADSL passthrough=no

# This marks all traffic coming from ether3_3G to get out through there too
add action=mark-routing chain=prerouting in-interface=ether3_3G \
    new-routing-mark=to_ether3_3G passthrough=no

/ip firewall nat
add action=masquerade chain=srcnat out-interface=ether2_ADSL
add action=masquerade chain=srcnat out-interface=ether3_3G

# This is just an example web server listening in port 8069, for testing purposes
add action=dst-nat chain=dstnat comment="Test server" dst-port=8069 \
    in-interface=ether2_ADSL protocol=tcp to-addresses=192.168.0.156 \
    to-ports=8069
add action=dst-nat chain=dstnat comment="Test server" dst-port=8069 \
    in-interface=ether3_3G protocol=tcp to-addresses=192.168.0.156 \
    to-ports=8069

/ip route

# Outgoing traffic by routing-mark
add check-gateway=ping distance=10 gateway=192.168.3.1 routing-mark=\
    to_ether3_3G
add check-gateway=ping distance=10 gateway=192.168.2.1 routing-mark=\
    to_ether2_ADSL

# Outgoing traffic by default
add check-gateway=ping distance=20 gateway=192.168.2.1
add check-gateway=ping distance=30 gateway=192.168.3.1
```

With this configuration, all traffic goes out by *ether3_3G* only if *ether2_ADSL* fails, and by *ether2_ADSL* otherwise (most of the time).

Now the problem is that incoming connections only work through *ether2_ADSL*. Connections incoming from *ether3_3G* get always stuck in `syn received` state.

It seems to me that incoming connections from *ether3_3G* reach the target server, but the response goes out through *ether2_ADSL* and that's why the TCP handshake never completes. In fact, if I physically unplug the *ether2_ADSL* cable, then all connections to/from *ether3_3G* start working OK.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to mark the connections coming from ether3_3G so that you can then mark the replies to be routed back via ether3_3G.

Here's an example configuration (not tested)

```
/ip firewall mangle
add action=mark-connection chain=prerouting comment="Mark connection so packets from 3G get returned to 3G properly" disabled=no in-interface=ether3_3G new-connection-mark=3g-packets passthrough=no
add action=mark-routing chain=prerouting connection-mark=3g-packets disabled=no new-routing-mark=3g-packets passthrough=no
add action=mark-routing chain=output connection-mark=3g-packets disabled=no new-routing-mark=3g-packets passthrough=no


/ip route
add disabled=no distance=1 dst-address=0.0.0.0/0 gateway=192.168.3.1 routing-mark=3g-packets
```

The first rule will place a `connection-mark` on any packet arriving from ether3_3G interface.

The second and third rule will 'catch' the replies back based on that connection mark and then place a `routing-mark` on those connections.

The second rule is for packets that are essentially forwarded and the third rule is for replies that the router itself will send (e.g. pings)

Finally the static route at the end will route the packets with the appropriate routing-mark via the ether3_3G interface.

Comment: Is not that essentially what I am already doing? I skip the step of mark connection, but that seems a unneeded step since you can mark routing directly.

Comment: You are not doing the same thing. `Routing marks` and `Connection marks` are *not* the same. When you place a routing mark on a packet that comes in, that mark won't be accessible after the reply back (from the router if it's a local service or from the server if it's port forwarded to another server). You need `connection marking` to match the packets going back back out and *then* do your routing marking on those packets.

Comment: You were right, thanks for the explanation. It works now. BTW, there is a typo: the last line should route to `192.168.3.1`.